# CSS - Class selector not working in IExplorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I dinamically create the following div structure:

```
<div id=Box>
   <div id=outer>
       <div id="inner1" class="split_right">
          some 
       </div>
       <div id="inner2" class="split_left">
          some 
       </div>
          .....
          .....
       <div id="inner(n)" class="split_right">
          some 
       </div>
       <div id="inner(n+1)" class="split_left">
          some 
       </div>

   </div>
</div>
```

The number of divs is dependent on the number of s passed in one array.
The problem is, that I want to give a css rule to split_right and split_left like this:

```
.split_left {
float: left;
margin: 0px 10px 5px 10px;
}
.split_right {
float: right;
margin: 0px 10px 5px 10px;
}
```

This works fine on chrome and safari but doesn't work in any IE6+

What am I doing wrong??

**UPDATE**

This is what I am trying to do:

http://postimage.org/image/g2t4qsq4v/

The outer div has a fixed width equal to 2*inner div width + 50pixels so that 2 s fit together in the same line.

Comment: What does not work float or margin?

Comment: Why not just float the images directly, without a wrapper?

Comment: You should really put quotes around the xml attributes, maybe that will help.

Comment: this is [online demo](http://jsfiddle.net/matmuchrapna/LEPmA/1/) of your html&css

please provide image of ie bug, and explain it

Comment: @Diodeus - Because I mean to have only 2 images per "line"

Comment: @thatidiotguy - that was a mistake writing the post. The code has the quotes correctly

Comment: @matmuchrapna The problem seems to be that the css selector is not selecting the class splitDiv in IE

Answer (score 1):

Try it with this:

```
<div id=Box>
   <div id=outer>
       <div id=inner1 class="split_right">
          some image
       </div>
       <div id=inner2 class="split_left">
          some image
       </div>
          .....
          .....
       <div id=inner(n) class="split_right">
          some image
       </div>
       <div id=inner(n+1) class="split_left">
          some image
       </div>

   </div>
</div>
```

You have forgotten the quotes

Comment: I forgot the quotes when I was writing the post but I have them in the code

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what is not working in IE and I don't know if you have a wrapper with a defined width that fits those just perfectly. But there is a famous bug in IE 6.. maybe 7 too I am not sure. If you have float left and margin in the same direction for example float left, and margin left xx number of pixels in IE 6 it will double the margin. So if you do have a define spaced that those boxes supposed to fit into, in IE it will most likely wrap to the next line making it look like it is not floating

add

```
display: inline;
```

to the css of each split class

Comment: Already tried it and the problem remains. The width of the "outer" div is more than twice the width of each "inner" div, so they should fit. And also I removed the margin.